# Using LayoutParams on While loop Java, Android

Tags: java, android, layoutparams

It seems like I have a problem with java code where I want to use ***LayoutParams*** in ***while*** loop.

So in this code, I thought it might be like this but not working.

If is **width** and **height** of the image **> 0** , then start looping by subtracting **height** and **width** till **0**.

Does anyone have some fix for this?

Here is the code:

```
 public void run() {


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myBall.getLayoutParams();


    while ((params.height > 0) && (params.width > 0)) {
        params.width--;
        params.height--;
        myBall.setLayoutParams(params);
}}
```

Comment: Why you are doing this  in run ? Do you want a animation ?

Comment: It's like animation, I'm trying to make code that resize width and height of the image till it's gone.

Comment: I mean by decreasing Height and width, you are doing a animation ?

Comment: Let's say "Animation" but it mustn't be repeatable. So image is resizing till 0, so it will be gone.

Comment: Actually by doing this 1) your view is not "gone" it will be still there 2) You will not see anything happening because View height and width diminishes in few milliseconds , You can't even see it shrinking.

Comment: So how can i see it shrinking?

Comment: How could i help if you don't want any animation to be included. It gonna be more easier I guess.

Comment: With Animation, I will not get what i need actually. This is not the only one "Scene" (code). There are more codes, so I can't use animation for this type.

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you want, Only then i can help.

Comment: Sorry but I can not explain, It's too hard. :(
Thank you

Comment: Great, I am seeing this first time here. Put some images, give some example, How i could help ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this

Create a folder named anim in your res and add anim_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:toYScale="0" >
    </scale>

    <alpha
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromAlpha="1"

        android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```

do this in your main java,

```
//Your view could be any View or ViewGroup
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.view1);
view.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.anim_out));
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Try this and tell me :). Happy coding

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it like this:

```
 public void run() {
    while ((myBall.getLayoutParams().height > 0) && (myBall.getLayoutParams().width > 0))
    {
        myBall.getLayoutParams().width--;
        myBall.getLayoutParams().height--;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it did the trick.

Comment: Everything in android studio is fine, but when i run it on any device it unfortunately stopped

Comment: okay but there must be something in Log, some exception thrown. What was it?